# Is it safe to remove read-only attribute from wwwroot?

Tags: permissions, iis, windows-server

I have recently moved to a windows 2012 R2 serevr. I have problem for deleting files through HTTP even though I have granted modify,write and read permissions to IIS_ISURS. I noticed that `inetpub/wwwroot` folder is read-only by default. Is it safe to uncheck the read-only attribute from this folder or there are alternative settings for modifying or deleting files through IIS settings etc.?

Answer (score -1):

No it is not safe to grant IIS_USRS any kind of write access. This would give an attacker a chance for example to create a webshell if he found the right entry point. By default and for good reason it has only read and execute permissions.

If you need to write new files or edit existing do that through a different process and account not linked to the IIS application pool running the main site.

This question's answers are also relevant

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319955/what-are-the-security-effects-of-giving-the-iis-iusrs-a-full-control-permission